tls and wireshark, Hello Server/Hello client aren't decodified
I'm using wireshark to analyse a tls connection, but wireshark doesn't show the connection with Hello Server/Client and so on. In  protocol preferences, "Allow subdissector to reassemble TCP streams" is flagged, and also "Reassemble out-of-order segments" is flagged. I'm using 4.4.1 version.
Any suggestion please?
Thank you.
Isabella

You shouldn't have to do anything special to see those messages. Are you sure you are filtering on the right adapters/IPs/ports?
